# BibTeX shows additional parenthesis depending on the author list

Tags: bibtex

I want to reference two ArXiv-papers from the same first author. However, something weird happens, when I append a third author to one of the papers. 
Both entries in the bibliography show an additional pair of parentheses () that is actually intended to give the year. 
But in this case, I don't want to specify the year!

In the minimal example that I attached, the parenthesis vanish when "Goofy Goof" is removed from the author list of "disney2015".

It looks to me very much like a bug in bibtex or in this style class. 
Can somebody help me with that?

I would like to know whether it happens to you as well. I tried it with bibtex 0.99d and kpathsea 6.1.0 and kpathsea 6.1.1

I would like to show you my example bibtex file (`bibtest.bib`):

```
@article{disney2013,
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {1307.9998},
author = {Donald Duck and Dagobert Duck and Daisy Duck and Mickey Mouse},
eprint = {1307.9998},
url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.9998}
}

@article{disney2015,
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {1411.9999},
eprint = {1411.9999},
author = {Donald Duck and Pippi Longstockings  and Goofy Goof},
url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.9999}
}

@article{disney2017,
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {1411.9997},
eprint = {1411.9997},
author = {Mickey Mouse},
url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.9997}
}
```

That could be run from this tex file:

```
\documentclass[superscriptaddress,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
        \cite{disney2015}
        \cite{disney2013}
        \cite{disney2017}
        \bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
        \bibliography{bibtest}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in Advance, 
Mechanix

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think this has to do with the first two papers having the same first author, but it's quite unclear what's really triggering the behavior.

Comment: You wrote, "It looks to me very much like a bug in bibtex or in this style class." Actually, there's no bug in either bibtex *or* the document class. Instead, the issue you're encountering is caused by the fact that you're using an inappropriate entry type. For arxiv publications, do *not* use the `@article` entry type, which requires the fields `year` and `journal`. Instead, use the `@misc` entry type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear to me.  Are you forced to use the document class and the `bst` you used in your MWE? For example, for publishing an article?  **Then do not change the predefined behaviour of the template you use!**

If you are not forced to use the class and bibliography style, why do you not just use another one?  It is much easier to customize `biblatex` than to create an own style with `makebst`.

The specific reason for the parenthes-related issues you're encountering is that you're using a bibliography style which requires a `year` field if the entry is of type `@article`. (Separately, there's also an issue with missing `journal` fields; more about that later.) That's why you get an empty `()` pair when you omit the `year` field. Because the style is not designed *not* to have a `year` field for entries of type `@article`, no test is performed to check if the field is missing. So the "error" you get is more a feature than a bug, because you're using the entry type in a way it is not built for.

Your MWE generates several warnings you should read and correct. For example, you need to add a class option for the society and journal.

You also provide the file extensions `.bst` for the style (don't!) and `.bib` for the bib file (don't!) in the arguments of `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography`. Finally, if you want to get rid of warnings about the missing field `journal`, you have to add something like `journal = {MISSING},` (change `MISSING` to what you need) to each of your bib entries.

Please see the following MWE. I've added class options, augmented the entries with `year` and `journal` fields, and corrected the syntax of the `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` directives.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{disney2013,
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  arxivId = {1307.9998},
  author = {Donald Duck and Dagobert Duck and Daisy Duck and Mickey Mouse},
  eprint = {1307.9998},
  journal = {MISSING},
  url    = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.9998},
  year = {2001},
}

@article{disney2015,
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  arxivId = {1411.9999},
  eprint = {1411.9999},
  author = {Donald Duck and Pippi Longstockings  and Goofy Goof},
  journal = {MISSING},
  url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.9999},
  year = {2002},
}

@article{disney2017,
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  arxivId = {1411.9997},
  eprint = {1411.9997},
  author = {Mickey Mouse},
  url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.9997},
  journal = {MISSING},
  year = {2003},
}
\end{filecontents*}    

\documentclass[%
  superscriptaddress,twocolumn,
  10pt,
  pra, aps % society=aps, journal=pra
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
\cite{disney2015}
\cite{disney2013}
\cite{disney2017}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1} % no .bst
\bibliography{\jobname} % no .bib
\end{document}
```

If you insist in not writing an year into the bib file (Why btw?) you have to copy the used style file and change it or better to use `biblatex` and the possibilities to customize it ...

## Edit:

As @Mico mentioned in his comment I add his advice here:

Instead of back-filling the missing `journal` and `year` fields for entries of type `@article`, which sort of treats the symptoms of the problem, why not treat the cause of the problem directly? My recommendation would be not to use the entry type `@article` for *arxiv publications*. Instead, I'd use the entry type `@misc`, which doesn't require the `year` field to begin with (or the `journal` field, for that matter).

Comment: It's fine -- in fact, i was hoping you'd take the comments on board. :-) I'll delete my comment now.